# DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future. print(np.array(result)==label_test[:2000])

Tags: python, numpy, knn

1.I want to check the accuracy of the classifier I just used code below:

```
print((np.array(result)==label_test[:2000]).mean())
```

2.result is a list so I just change it to a NumPy array, then check how many labels are the same as label_test. However, it did not work. The error message says that DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.   print(np.array(result)==label_test[:2000])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the length of the operands are not matching.
ie, len(result) and len(label_test[:2000]) are different. Both operands should be of same size to perform elementwise comparison.